Can I drive my AWD vehicle as FWD by removing the propshaft?
I have of heard people removing their propshaft on their AWD vehicle to narrow down a diagnosis with their drive train. Is generally
safe to do or could there be consequences to removing this part?
Would there be a need to realign the transfer case mount to the rear diff mount on the opposite end to make sure they’re not out of phase with one another when the propshaft eventually gets replaced? I would think the two rotating mounts would get out of phase just in normal driving as one axle turns faster than another and incrementally one advances past the other over time.

What is the year/make/model of the vehicle in question?

While not a common thing, removing the tailshaft is not unheard of to deal with damage to a 4WD in remote areas, allowing it to limp home in FWD. Depends on how comfortable you feel about doing it yourself once you look at the shaft connections.
